# I need to shift characters around in a character varying column in postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a column with date and timestamp stored as character varying, I need to join to another table that has the same dates (also stored as character varying) but in different positions.

IE is there a way to convert:

```
"2022/08/03 13:29:59" ----------> "03/08/2022 13:29:59"
```

Thanks

Comment: if possible, wouldn't be better to change both columns to `timestamp`?

Comment: see it yourself: `SELECT 
  '2022/08/03 13:29:59'::timestamp,
  '03/08/2022 13:29:59'::timestamp`

Comment: Thanks Jim, this is a much better option!!

Comment: I just added an answer with a fiddle that might make my case better. cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way would be to change the data type of both columns, as timestamps shouldn't be stored as text. If not possible, a simple cast would do:

```
SELECT 
  '2022/08/03 13:29:59'::timestamp,
  '03/08/2022 13:29:59'::timestamp;

      timestamp      |      timestamp      
---------------------+---------------------
 2022-08-03 13:29:59 | 2022-08-03 13:29:59
(1 row)
```

Demo: [`db<>fiddle`](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=41cd632e14222594029c0245236550ca)